# How to make object non-transparent in viewport?

Tags: mesh, texturing, objects, transparency, color

In the viewport I can see through my character, when I render it out it is normal, I'm just wondering how to fix this. I exported this from Maya.[image: Transparent Lion]

Comment: Scroll down in your material settings and try enabling _Backface Culling_.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work, so I started playing around with the material settings. Right below "backface Culling" is "Show backface", I turned it off and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turn off "Show backface" in the material settings. You'll have to do this for all the materials individually.